Goroutine was not preempt when gc stw
my golang version was 1.20.
I watch over 90 ms stw time in trace pprof, when i analyze this pprof, i find some goroutine was not preempt for 80ms, which lead to the stw time become too long
such as the G416255369 in this picture
this is my trace pprof screencut
I would like to know the possible reasons that lead to this situation（readLoop goroutine G416255369 was not preempt over 80ms）.

My program was exec in one pod of k8s. So i have a thought: if the thread M which the G416255369 is executing on have be scheduled by os, because the cgroup was been cpu throttled.  does this situation can lead to the G416255369 can't be preempted? because the M doesn't exec on computer.
